# i can't access public dataset, which create in master page, in the child pages.how i can access..?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i create public dataset named "pub_dset" in master page and fill it.and now i am unable to access "pub_dset" in the child pages.how i can access this dataset "pub_dst" in child table.

the code of createing dataset and fill it in master page is:

```
Public pub_dset As New DataSet
cmd.CommandText = "Author_search"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
p = New SqlParameter
p.ParameterName = "@author_id"
p.Value = Session("author_id")
cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
dpt.SelectCommand = cmd
dpt.Fill(pub_dset, "tab")
name_LinkButton.Text = pub_dset.Tables("tab").Rows(0("author_first_name")
ImageButton1.ImageUrl = pub_dset.Tables("tab").Rows(0)("author_image")
```

dataset fill properly but it is not accessable in child pages.what should i do..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enable access to the Master Page with a property. Then you can access it's methods and variables. `Site1` is the class name of the Master Page.

```
public Site1 master;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    master = (Site1)Page.Master;
}
```

VB

```
Dim master As Site1

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    master = CType(Page.Master,Site1)
End Sub
```

So then you can do this

```
master.pub_dset = new DataSet();
```